# Codeigniter + Composer

Tags: php, codeigniter, composer-php, autoload

I would like to start learning `Codeigniter`. But it seems that Codeigniter has not support for installation via Composer. When I search in Google I found this [link](http://codesamplez.com/development/composer-with-codeigniter). It seems that Codeigniter has not support for autoload.php file created by Composer. The documentation describes the only installation via downloading .zip archive. I am not sure if Codeigniter is a good choice now. Is it?

Answer (score 31):

It has composer support in version 3. According to [the documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/autoloader.html?highlight=composer) you can set in application/config/config.php .

```
$config['composer_autoload'] = TRUE;  //around 134 line
```

It will search for composer autoload script inside `application/vendor` . Place `composer.json` inside application(Codeigniter's application folder, not the root) folder. Then run `composer init`, and then - `composer install`.

And if CI fits you, then its right tool for your job:)

p.s. there is also a composer installer here https://github.com/kenjis/codeigniter-composer-installer

Comment: Just to expand on this. If you want to install composer somewhere else you can set that config to the composer path instead of just TRUE

Comment: I found it in config. But it seems it only support including autoload file created by Composer. Is there a way to install(create project) whole Codeigniter via Composer with all necessary settings?

Comment: I just created an empty composer.json. is it mandatory to add at least one plugin inside json to run init because I am getting "./composer.json" does not contain valid json.

Comment: you don't have to add libraries, just start with composer init inside directory, it will guide you and produce valid composer.json file

Answer (score 13):

use the following code

```
composer create-project kenjis/codeigniter-composer-installer codeigniter
```

[Source](https://github.com/kenjis/codeigniter-composer-installer)

Answer (score 9):

According to the documentation you can configure the config.php file inside config folder,

change the `$config['composer_autoload']` line to

```
$config['composer_autoload'] = TRUE;
```

or use path

```
$config['composer_autoload'] = FCPATH . 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

Answer (score 2):

Tips 1:

A Multi-Framework Composer Library Installer

http://composer.github.com/installers

Tips 2:

```
composer create-project kenjis/codeigniter-composer-installer codeigniter
```